# Analytically determine the range of the function for $f(x) = \left|\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right|$

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

How can I analytically determine the range of the function?

$$f(x) = \left|\frac{x-2}{x+3}\right|$$

If I have an ordinary linear equation, I'd proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = x + 2 \Rightarrow y = x + 2 \Rightarrow y - 2 = x
\end{align*}
then the range of the function is $\mathbb{R}$, but I do not see what to do here.

The result is $[0,\infty)$.

But I want to find out the range numerically, not just estimate it from the graph

I speak about this range.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CqVV.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But I want to find out the range numerically, not just estimate it from the graph

Comment: Have you tried writing the function in piecewise form and analyzing its behavior in the intervals $(-\infty, -3)$, $(-3, 2)$, and $[2, \infty)$?

Comment: It's not wrong to ask about a similar topic, but it doesn't seem nice that their "effort" to solve the problem is the same as the link here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4556092/1027216. A different user but an undeniable similarity. When you are asked to show your effort it is in order to know how we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, I'd find the range of the function $g(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+3},$ since $f(x)=\bigl|g(x)\bigr|.$ To do this, first note that $x$ cannot be equal to $-3,$ take an arbitrary $y$ and set $g(x)=y,$ that is, $$\frac{x-2}{x+3}=y,$$ so that you can solve for $x.$ The first step in this process is to note that since $x\neq -3,$ then $$x-2=(x-3)y.$$ By the end, you'll have an equation of the form $$x=\frac{ay+b}{cy+d}.$$ From this, you'll be able to find the one value that $y$ cannot take in the equation $g(x)=y,$ which will tell you the range of $g,$ from which you'll conclude the range of $f.$